# Fast eventHandler calls causing skipping code

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

I'm having an eventHandler on mouseEnter in which I have simple linear complexity code, where I add and remove some values to and from List. The thing is, that when I tick the event slowly, everything works, but when I tick it at normal speed ( as a user will do ) or fast, the program skips a part of a code(I can see it visualy as its drawing some objects) causing the List being unstable.

I heard that there isn't way to do this via locking, because all UI calls are processed in a single thread.

I need the code to be executed whole and correctly for the price of some events(mouse enter) being unnoticed.

Here's the handler function:

```
public static void HandleMouseEnter(object sender)
        {          
                    for (int i = 0; i < currentlyPrebuilt.Count; i++)
                    {
                        currentlyPrebuilt[i].Image = null;
                    }
                    currentlyPrebuilt.Clear();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= sender.x - startingPoint.x; i++) 
                    {
                        currentlyPrebuilt.Add(pictures[i]); 
                        pictures[i].Image = "sth.jpg";
                    }                    
            }
        }
```

It just doesn't set null to all Images in the List if moving too fast with mouse

Comment: Posting your code would be helpful.

Comment: It is almost impossible to behave like you say unless something is lurking in your code. Maybe someone alters the currentlyPrebuild collection on another thread... we must see your code.